# Python 2.7 While Loop time

Tags: python

```
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now.second == 1:
        print "One"
```

my program print One about 7 times.  How do I make it print only once?

Comment: My first thought is to make it `time.sleep(1)` after, but that's probably evil :P

Comment: Are you sure, it's about 7 times? Well, that's extremely low number, to be honest. That means, your computer check for now value takes about 0.14 second.
By the way, please, correct the indentation in your quote.

Comment: @Gandi, good point. mine prints more than stdout can deal with so in the thousands.

Comment: Well, there always can be a counter in the loop. Each time the counter will go to some value, it can print "One" and get zeroed. This value is not hard to count. Simply multiply your PC clock frequency with a number 60 (number of seconds in a minute). Oh, and don't forget to think about old, assembler times while writing this ;)

Comment: @Gandi - on C64's Basic, an empty FOR loop of 590 iterations took quite exactly one second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computer is too fast.

It takes the current time, tests whether the current second is one and then again. And since it is so fast it can do this within less than one second, you get more lines of output.

Make it wait after each iteration:

```
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now.second == 1:
        print "One"
        time.sleep(59) # wait 59 seconds after success
    time.sleep(1) # wait 1 second after each fail
```

This program will sleep most time. If you want it to do anything useful, it will be a different program.

Comment: time.sleep(2) # wait 2 seconds
is not enough? (For too slow computers...)

Comment: Plus trusting `time.sleep` is a little foolish it's notoriously inaccurate because it must rely on the system as well. You're better of halving those times.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the value previously used for printing?

```
previous = None
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now.second == 1 and now.second != previous:
        print "One"
        previous = now.second # store the last value
```

Comment: are you sure? previous is always 1

Comment: Instead of storing now.second in previous, store now.